# get value to marking on calender from date picker

Tags: android, date, datepicker, calendar

## Get value from date picker then set on intent calender

This is my code, need your help :)

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   public int year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   public int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
   public int day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);   
   return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

}
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bTnCalander.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CallCalender();
        }
    });
}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

  private void CallCalender() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("minutes", METHOD_ALARM);
    intent.putExtra("allDay", false);enter code here
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

I am facing a problem, how I can get value from date picker, than that value before and then will mark on Intent Calender.

Answer (score 0):

When you call,

`return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);`

You need to specify the `OnDateSetListener` where you place `this`, here is an example I worked out for you,

```
//Create your own OnDateSetListener which will be called every time you set a new date in your calendar
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        //We will display a toast so that we see it works
        String myDate = "Year:" + year +"\nmonth:" + month + "\nDayOfMonth:" + dayOfMonth;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),myDate,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Here you would add all logic you want when the user sets a new date in our DatePicker
    }
};

//We will get the current instance to initialize our DatePickerDialog
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, myListener, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

//Display our DatePickerDialog
dialog.show();
```